# How to define and consume enums in typescript when using AMD?

Tags: typescript, amd

The following tsc command doesn't create a usable foo.d.ts:

```
TSC -declaration -m amd foo.ts
```

foo.ts:

```
export enum foo {
    bar
}
```

foo.d.ts:

```
export declare enum foo {
    bar,
}
```

But

```
///<reference path="./foo.d.ts"/>
```

doesn't work until the "export" is removed fro foo.d.ts.  Is there another way of declaring a variable of type foo in a second file?  Seems to me referencing foo.ts should have worked (it didn't):

```
///<reference path="./foo.ts"/>
```

Am I missing a keyword?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are working with external modules in TypeScript `///<reference` comments are not relevant.

To import the type into another file you need to do:

```
import mod = require('./foo'); 
// Then access the enum object as : mod.foo
```

To learn about internal vs. external modules check out this short video tutorial I made : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: It's fine to compile with --declaration with external modules; the compiler will preferentially use foo.d.ts over foo.ts when resolving the import (and this will be significantly faster to compile)

Comment: Thanks @RyanCavanaugh, then I guess there is a compiler bug that is generating `export declare`? Also I was of the opinion that a file level export creates a namespace which makes everything in the file hidden if you do `///<reference` for such a file based on this: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1404. Am I wrong? If not, wouldn't that make `///<reference`ing external module files redundant?

Comment: @basarat: I'm using typescript for static type checking only.  I'm using require(["./foo"], function (foo: foo) {}) syntax.  Present workaround is to wrap all my enums in one module then I only have to delete a single "export".  It requires maintaining a simple interface that *should* be handled by --declaration IMO but since a module is not a type it doesn't work.  For example, foo.ts: export module m { export enum f { b } }, becomes foo.d.ts: declare module m{ enum f{b,}} so I can't use m as a type.

Comment: @basarat: I now understand that the import goes directly in the .d.ts file.  I didn't realize that was an option but make sense.

Comment: With `typescript@1.5.3` accessing `mod.foo` with give `error TS2503: Cannot find namespace`.